# get metadata from a pdf file in ruby

Tags: ruby, pdf, rubygems, pdf-reader

I am trying to read unique number from pdf by "pdf-reader" gem but for some reason its not reading just that page. other then the first page, all pages read ok. when it reads, it returns empty.

```
I am using following code

      reader = PDF::Reader.new(filename)
      reader.pages.each do |page|
        puts page.text
      end
```

Comment: Can you share this document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Fixed by reading from raw data..
```

thanks for help.